# reoprt viewer always redirecting to SSRS home page

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my web application, i am using report viewer to view ssrs reports i am passing parameters to report viewer as

> Me.ReportViewer1.ServerUrl = "Name of
>   Server/reportServer_instance_name" Me.ReportViewer1.ReportPath =
>   "/Folder_name/ReportName"

But it always pointing to SSRS home page  but not to the Report

Comment: If you are seeing the ssrs home page then your endpoints are correct. What is displayed at the ssrs the home page?

Comment: All the contents i can see means folder structures

Comment: Did you typo the report name? This is sounding like a authentication issue.

Comment: I got the solution, I am giving http://servername/report instead of http://servername/reportServer.
Server need to bind to the report server instance name